Convert normal html text to display as an image
I am trying to display normal HTML to load as an image on my page.
For example:
<h1>Hello World</h1>

This will display text on my page.
How do I convert this so that the h1 tag will display "Hello World"  as an image on my page?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would also like to see what answers are given for this.

I've rather rashly assumed you can add some javascript, if you need to, @Karen ?

Why do you want to do this?

Presumably the HTML needs to be dynamic? Otherwise you could just make a static image in advance (e.g. screenshot the rendered HTML). Some context on why you want to do this might help steer the answers in the right direction.

I think you could use canvas element to render an image. More documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid grey;">
Sorry, your browser does not support canvas.
</canvas>

<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "50px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,80);
</script>




I think the easiest way would be to add the text to a hidden canvas tag, then use toDataURL.
The javascript:
var cnvs = document.getElementById('cnvs').getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById('img');
  
document.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('keyup', function()
{
  cnvs.canvas.width = cnvs.measureText(this.value).width;
  cnvs.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
  img.src = cnvs.canvas.toDataURL();
}, false);

The css:
#cnvs
{
 display: none;
}

The html:
<canvas id='cnvs'></canvas>
<img id='img'/>
<br/>
<textarea id='txt'></textarea>

